# How to Check if a link is active or inactive by using the class in Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to Click on a link and check that it is active. However the class is what is determining whether it is active or not.
This is for pagination for a web page where i want to automate the web driver to navigate to different pages and ensure the link click has indeed taken the user to the correct page.

I am using Selenium2Library with firefox.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: which binding you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's solution in Java, I hope you can translate it to whatever language you use.

```java
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[title='No. 2']"));
String linkClass = link.findElement(By.xpath("./..")).getAttribute("class");
if ("active".equals(linkClass)) {
   link.click();
}
```

Comment: You mean Selenium IDE?